# list.isEmpty() or list.size() not working in an if loop in java

Tags: java, multithreading, list, queue

[image]

I am using java for sending streams at given rate(say 100 events/sec) via UDP to another receiver program. The receiver program has 2 threads. Thread 1 appends the values to List and another thread is checking is the list has some element and perform some action on it.

Earlier, I have been using a queue instead of a list. I was having issues with Iterator thread while checking if the queue has some element or not. It's a wired problem, I may be making some silly mistake. For this reason, I decided to use List, but I am having same issues now.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Code of Sender Program is

```
public class simpleGen {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Integer arrival_rate = 1;
        Integer sleep_time = 1000/arrival_rate;

        Long currentTime;
        Integer value = null;
        Integer Sensor_id;
        Integer Patient_id;
        Integer uid = 0;
        Long count = 0L;


        Integer time_in_sec = 60*2 ;
        Integer lower_bound = 10;
        Integer upper_bound = 20;


        Long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Long end_time = start_time + (1000 * time_in_sec);


            int server_port = 8000;
            DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
             s.setSendBufferSize(2147483647);
            InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName("172.17.195.107");


        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end_time) {

            uid = 1;
            count += 1;

            Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

            Patient_id = 1;
            Sensor_id = 1;

            currentTime = System.nanoTime();

            value = lower_bound + random.nextInt((upper_bound - lower_bound) + 1);

            Event event = new Event(Patient_id, Sensor_id, uid, currentTime, value);


            String messageStr = event.toString();
//            System.out.println(messageStr);


            int msg_length = messageStr.length();
            byte[] message = messageStr.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, msg_length, local, server_port);
            s.send(p);

            System.out.print(" \r   Sensor 1 count = " + count );
            System.out.flush();


            Thread.sleep(sleep_time );

        }


        Float inpt_rate = Float.valueOf(count)/time_in_sec;

        System.out.println(" \n Average output rate = " + inpt_rate + " events/second" );
    }


}
```

Code of Receiver Program is

```
public class Simplereceiver {

    public static final String ANSI_RED     = "\u001B[31m";
    public static final String ANSI_BLUE    = "\u001B[34m";
    public static final String ANSI_PURPLE  = "\u001B[35m";


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception

    {

        Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();



    Thread iterating_thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println( ANSI_BLUE + " iterating_thread  started");

            Boolean running = true ;

            while(running){

                if(list.size() > 0){

                    System.out.println("has element ----");
                    System.out.println(list.size());

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }

    }};

    Thread receiving_thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {


            Integer total_re_ECG = 0;
            String[] sensor_value = new String[10];
            String[] parsed_tuple = new String[10];


            boolean run = true;
            DatagramSocket udpSocket = null;
            DatagramPacket packet = null;
            try {
                udpSocket = new DatagramSocket(8000);
                udpSocket.setReceiveBufferSize(2147483647);
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] message = new byte[8000];
            packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);


            System.out.println( ANSI_RED + " receiving_thread  started");

            while (run) {



                try {

//              Block until the host receives a UDP packet.
                    udpSocket.receive(packet);

                    String text = new String(message, 0, packet.getLength());

                    String[] tupleData = text.split(",");

                    int i = 0;


                    for (String tuple : tupleData) {
                        String[] tupleValue = tuple.split("=");

                        sensor_value[i] = tupleValue[1];
                        i += 1;

                    }// key pair of tuple ends

                    total_re_ECG += 1;
                    Integer patient_id = Integer.valueOf(sensor_value[0]);
                    Integer sensor_id = Integer.valueOf(sensor_value[1]);
                    Integer tuple_id = Integer.valueOf(sensor_value[2]);
                    Long generation_time = Long.valueOf(sensor_value[3]);
                    Float sensor1_data = Float.valueOf(sensor_value[4]);
                    Long event_arrival_time = System.nanoTime();

//                System.out.println(event_arrival_time);

                    parsed_tuple[0] = total_re_ECG + "," + event_arrival_time ;
//                    queue.add(String.valueOf(sensor1_data));
                    list.add(String.valueOf(sensor1_data));



                    System.out.println("packet added is = " + parsed_tuple[0]);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    run = false;
                }//catch
            }//while



        }
    };

    receiving_thread.start();
    iterating_thread.start();


    }//main

}//class
```

Comment: Well which specific List implementation are you using - and have you chosen a thread-safe one?

Comment: Which list are you using? ArrayList, LinkedList or any threadsafe list?

Comment: What isn't working ? You get a stacktrace ? Or is it something else ?

Comment: @Amit: Thanks for replying. I have updated the code in original question. I am using ArrayList

Comment: "*I was having issues with Iterator thread while checking if the queue has some element or not*" what exactly was that issue? Anyway this looks like producer-consumer problem which can be easily solved with collections like `BlockingQueue` (you can pick `LinkedBlockingQueue` (for infinite length), `ArrayBlockingQueue` (for N elements) or even `SynchronousQueue` (for 1 element)). Producer will need to `put` element (which will automatically wait if queue is full), consumer should `take` element (will automatically wait if there isn't any).

Comment: @AmarjitSingh What problem you are facing? Please post what is the expected behavior and what currently you are getting?

Comment: @Amit: When values are added to a list, if I try to check if the list has some value using an if (list.size() > 0), then even if the list has elements, it did not go inside if loop. On the other hand, if I use if(true) and print size of the list, I can see it getting incremented. Now the issue is that, why using if(list.size() > 0) don't work

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: It's not resolved yet by the comments above. Hence it's still an issue for me. I have provided the code as well

Comment: ?? You're using unsafe threading practices, and @Pshemo already told you to use basic producer / consumer techniques. Please consider following this advice.

Comment: @AmarjitSingh use CopyOnWriteArrayList or Collections.synchronizedList(list)

Answer (score 1):

Using LinkedBlockingQueue solved my issue

Updated code for Iterator Thread is

```
    Thread iterating_thread = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println( ANSI_BLUE + " iterating_thread  started");

        Boolean running = true ;

        while(running){

            if(!linkedBlockingQueue.isEmpty()){

                System.out.println(linkedBlockingQueue.element());
                linkedBlockingQueue.remove();

            }
        }
}};
```